# Copying to previous element in python

Tags: python, list

I have a variable called

```
total_path = [[['Start', ''], ['A', ''],['B', ''],['C', 'True']['E', '']['D', 'True'],['Enjoy!', '']], [['Start', ''], ['A', ''], ['B', ''] ['C', 'True'],['E', ''],['Enjoy!', 'False']],[['Start', ''], ['A', ''], ['B', ''], ['Enjoy!', 'False']]]
```

I want the expected output to be this, which basically is shifting all the True and False to the previous element

```
total_path = [[['Start', ''], ['A', ''], ['B', 'True'], ['C', ''], ['E', 'True'], ['D', ''], ['Enjoy!', '']]
 [['Start', ''], ['A', ''], ['B', 'True'], ['C', ''], ['E', 'False'], ['Enjoy!', '']]
[['Start', ''], ['A', ''], ['B', 'False'], ['Enjoy!', ''] ]]
```

This is the code I'm writing

```
for i in range(len(total_path)) :
    for j in range(len(total_path[i])):
        if len(total_path[i][j][1]) and j :
            total_path[i][j-1][1]   =  total_path[i][j][1]  
            total_path[i][j][1] = ''
```

However it gives some random output like

```
total_path =  [[['Start', 'True'],['A', ''],['B', 'False'], ['C', 'True'], ['E', 'False'], ['D', ''], ['Enjoy!', '']],
 [['Start', 'True'], ['A', ''], ['B', 'False'],['C', 'True'],['E', 'False'],['Enjoy!', '']],
 [['Start', 'True'], ['A', ''], ['B', 'False'], ['Enjoy!', '']]]
```

I can't seem to make out what is happening, this seems to be a very simple problem and yet I'm getting it wrong :(

Comment: Your variable isn't valid, it's not a valid python list. EDit it first. Secondly, can it be of arbitrary shape, for example 3d, 4d, 5d, or always the same shape

Comment: @AhsanulHaque I have edited it. It will always be of this form  [  [ [component1,component 2] ] , [ [ component 1, component 2 ] ] .... ]. Basically a list of nested lists and it can only be 2 elements in the final nested object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty easy to be honest. You can try this:

```
resulted_list = []
for i in total_path:
     first = [j[0] for j in i]
     second = [j[1] for j in i]
     resulted_list.append(list(zip(first, second[1:] + [''])))
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach might be:

```
result = [[[a[0], b[1]] for a, b in zip(x, [*x[1:], x[0]])] for x in total_path]
```

Answer (score 0):

I run your code and the output is actually correct.
I think you might have been run it multiple times so your `total_path` is corrupt.
Try to assign the original value to your `total_path` and run your code again.
Also, it is actually better to use a new variable when you need to change the value instead of modifying the original one to prevent it from corrupt.